# Learning Linear Mixed Models from a ANOVA background

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, anova, references

It is my first question, and I would like a recommendation from the community. I am having trouble understanding Linear Mixed models.

I have already tried to read some books and also tried some online courses (Datacamp), but I am still unable to crack this topic. One of my major problems is that I can not transpose my former knowledge from ANOVA statistics into this topic. Specifically, I would like to analyze experiments that could be analyzed with ANOVA with the linear mixed models approach instead. According to what I had read, linear mixed models are much more flexible should overcome ANOVA in the future. Does anyone have a recommendation of some time of materials that could help me? Or should I stick to ANOVA for my experiments?

Comment: I always recommend this tutorial from Bodo Winter, as he explains the concepts clearly and uses analogies that I think are pretty accesible. What you should remember is that ANOVAs are all just very specific versions, or 'special cases' of linear models. https://bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing the material. I had already this material some time ago. I will try to read it again.

Comment: I have always appreciated an article written by Yulia Marchenko in the Stata Journal on this topic. See https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X0600600101

Comment: Thanks! This will definitely help